# Do I need to buy a return ticket for my son coming here to Malaysia?

Tags: visas, filipino-citizens, malaysia

Do I need to buy a return ticket for my son from Phillipines when visiting Malaysia? By "return ticket" I mean Malaysia to Philippines route. I have a spouse visa and I plan for my son to stay for a few months in Malaysia. Can I just extend his visa every month at the immigration office here in Malaysia or is there any other procedure?

Comment: The airline that flies him from the Philippines is required to make sure his travel is within the legal rules of Malaysia.  If he has no departure ticket and no long stay visa then he will not be able to prove that he is leaving Malaysia before his initial entry permit expires, they will likely not let him board.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, you should have a return ticket for your son.  [Timatic](http://www.skyteam.com/en/Why-SkyTeam/Services/Visa-and-Health/):

> The following are exempt from holding a visa:
>
> Nationals of Philippines for **a maximum stay of 30 days**.
>
> Additional information:
>
> Visitors are required to hold proof of sufficient funds (at least USD
>   500.-.) to cover their stay.
>
> **Important: Nationals of Philippines not holding a return/onward ticket could be requested to purchase one or refused entry.**

Note the 30-day limit: you will need to get an advance tourist visa if you want your son to stay longer, or plead for a [visa extension on hardship grounds](http://www.travelfish.org/orientation_detail/malaysia/peninsular_malaysia/kuala_lumpur/kuala_lumpur/103).

Answer (score 1):

Current Malaysian Minimum  **Entry** Requirements as at  08/12/2019  for Tourists /Business Visitors /visit relatives /attending seminars.

1. CASH of RM 1,000
2. Tours Itinerary
3. Provide Hotel Bookings
4. Provide Invitation letters for Business Visits
5. Provide sponsors details for longer period of visit (max 30 days)
6. Provide a valid Return Ticket (Booking slips are rejected)
7. Provide a valid Outbound /onward Ticket for other destination country.
8. There must be a validity period of minimum 6 months in your passport.

Upon entry, you will be given a  **Visit Pass** stamp in your passport. This **visit pass** does not allow any extension. 
Those who are working in other countries (not in PH) are required to pre-apply a Visa to enter to visit Malaysia. Direct Flight Entry from PH need not apply as Filipinos are given Free Visa to enter and 30 days Visit Pass to live inside Malaysia.

Even if you have a "spouse visa" you do not have right to sponsor your son to be here in Malaysia. Your current husband is the sponsor for you only.

What you can do is that 1 week before the expiry of the 30 days visit pass, go to the Immigration and apply for an extension of 1 more month with the submission of valid documents.
Critical docs that may be able to help :-

1. Proof of relationship with you.
2. Proof of funds to sustain the duration of the extension.
3. A letter of approval from your husband can be handy.
4. Providence of a Air Ticket direct back to source country if requested. Do not buy first. If Immigration approves the application, you will have to buy a return ticket in order to collect a "extension special pass".

For this type of case, it is at the discretion of IMMigration to allow or reject the application. Last minute application will sure to be rejected.